# what are the use cases of type() function in python? specifically when i passed 3 arguments to it

Tags: python-3.x

I was studying python's type() function.
Its first application is to return the type of any python's object as follows:-

a = 5

type(a)

But in documentation there is another way of calling type() function by passing it three arguments as follows :-

X = type('X', (object,), dict(a=1))

This second call returning "type" class's object.
What are some use cases of this "type" class object?
Pleas elaborate.

[Here is the documentation link, which i have followed, but could not get any help regarding it's use cases](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=type%20function#type)

[Programiz's link, I have explored that as well, but unable to find any relevant stuff there as well](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use three arguments to create a new class.
The first argument is the class name that we are inheriting from. The second argument is the **bases** attribute (tuple containing all the base class) and in the third argument, we provide all declarations made in the class.
Now with an example,

```
>>> class X:
        a = 1
>>> Y = type('X', (object,), dict(a=10))
```

Here, 'Y' inherits from class 'X'.
The second argument only means that the object we are creating is of 'object' type.
The third argument is just declaration of definitions that were made in class 'X'. If you don't mention anything inside dict(), then there will be no new attribute in class 'Y'.

```
>>> Y = type('X', (object,), dict())
```

Now if you try,

```
>>> Y.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'X' has no attribute 'a'
```

Go through [this](https://www2.lib.uchicago.edu/keith/courses/python/class/5/) to understand the predefined attributes in Python.

Comment: i have some confusions there.lets take my example:-
a = type("abc", (int,),{"name":"ali"})
1)this working abslutely fine for me, enen i havn't created any class of  name "abc".
2)what would be the changes occur if i passes (int,) or any other python's object instead of(obj,).
3) what is the purpose of creating class in this manner?
4)type(a) returns me "type", what does it means?

Comment: (1) You are creating a new class "abc".This an entirely different way of creating classes. (2) No changes when you look at it really. __bases__ is just meta-data that really doesn't affect your class (3) Just another way. 4) All user-defined classes in python 3 are instances of object 'type', which is also a class on its own. (And also accept the answer if it was useful.)

Comment: Thanks for explanation.